# Event handling dynamic created buttons in Vue.js v-for loop

Tags: button, dynamic, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a v-for loop where a button is created for each iteration. I'm trying to make a toggle handler where clicking the button will toggle the color of the button. But since the buttons are dynamically created, all of their colors are changing ....

```
<div class="pets" v-for="pet in pets" :key="pet.id">
    <button class="favorite" v-on:click="toggle">
        <i v-bind:class="[{ 'red' : favorited }, 'material-icons']">favorite</i>
    </button>           
</div>
```

The pets array is being filled with a http call. My script looks like this:

```
<script>
export default {
    name: 'home',
    data() {
        return {
            pets: [],
            favorited: false
        }
    },
    methods: {
        toggle: function() {
            this.favorited = !this.favorited;
        }
    },
}
```

The Style tag just changes the color

```
<style scoped>
.red {
    color: red;
}
```

Essentially, I'm trying to created a favorite button where you can toggle favoriting an object from the array pets. I know why my method would activate all my buttons. Since favorited is not unique to a button and coming from the data. So when favorited = true, the class 'red' is bound to all my buttons. My question is how do I bind the class 'red' to just the button I click on? I'm relatively new to Vue and this is driving me nuts lol! Someone please tell me how I can fix this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add a favorited property to your pet objects in the pets array. Then use that property.

```
<div class="pets" v-for="pet in pets" :key="pet.id">
    <button class="favorite" v-on:click="pet.favorited = !pet.favorited">
        <i v-bind:class="[{ 'red' : pet.favorited }, 'material-icons']">favorite</i>
    </button>           
</div>
```

[Example](https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/rmvQGq?editors=1010).

If you didn't want to modify the pet object, then [here is an alternate way](https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/gWzQow?editors=1010).

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!